# Many text files are not indexed by default

Tags: recoll

Recoll does not index many text files by default. It seems to only index files where the mimemap explicitly includes the mime type, but not other "obvious" file types.

Examples:

- yaml files -- `file -i` shows `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` but using `recollindex -e -i /path/to/foo.yaml` shows recoll detecting it as `application/x-yaml` via `xdg-mime`, which isn't an officially registered mime type -- but if recoll uses `xdg-mime`, one would think it would know how to deal with all the possible return values from `xdg-mime`
- <strike>awk scripts -- same thing, with `application/x-awk`</strike> this **is** in the default `mimeconf`.
- <strike>perl scripts -- same thing, with `application/x-perl`</strike> this **is** in the default `mimeconf`.
- <strike>shell scripts -- same thing, with `application/x-shellscript`</strike> this **is** in the default `mimeconf`.
- kotlin and other source code files -- recoll sees it as `text/x-kotlin` -- again a non-standard type via `xdg-mime`, but one that begins with `text/` so Recoll should know it is text -- but still doesn't index it
- readme files -- same thing, with `text/x-readme`

Now, this can be worked around on a case-by-case basis by adding into `~/.recoll/mimeconf` something like:

```
[index]
application/x-yaml = internal text/plain
text/x-kotlin = internal text/plain
text/x-readme = internal text/plain
```

but doing this one file type at a time seems silly. Is there a way to say

1. index everything with mime type `text/*` as `text/plain`, unless recoll already has a more specific parser for the type
2. index obvious textual data (e.g. if `file -i` returns `text/plain`) as `text/plain`, again unless recoll already has a more specific parser for the type

If it matters, I'm using recoll packaged by Fedora.

Comment: When trying out some things for your question I had some success with `textunknownasplain = 1` combined with `usesystemfilecommand = 1` and `systemfilecommand = file -i` in `recoll.conf`. Not everything seemed to work though, I'm not really sure what is going on.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks -- `textunknownasplain` handles the `text/*` types properly, thank you. `systemfilecommand` I'd rather not override as that switches from the recommended `xdg-mime` to `file`, which is going to change too much default behavior. The only thing I can think to do is to review all the mime types from `/usr/share/mime/types` and explicitly add all the relevant text types to the index conf. I would have thought that since recoll uses `xdg-mime` by default, recoll would already handle all the relevant types. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer and I will upvote/accept it.

Comment: I installed recoll on Ubuntu and there `mimeconf` already has a quite large list of mime types, including awk, perl, and shellscript, but without yaml, kotlin and readme. Since those are relatively newer filetypes/mimetypes, maybe the goal was indeed to add all textual types to `mimeconf` but this just didn't get updated recently.

Comment: Yes, I was also just noticing the same thing! Looks like those entries in my custom `mimeconf` were redundant -- not sure why I put them there. Maybe an earlier version packaged for Fedora did not include them, but the current version does.